# C# powershell adsisearcher

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to find domain user by name in Powershell without RSAT module. The solution which I found is to use DirectorySearcher:

```
([adsisearcher]\"(&(objectCategory=user)(sAMAccountName=test))\").FindAll()
```

It works well in Powershell, but doesn't work from C# using System.Management.Automation.Powershell class.

```
using var ps = PowerShell.Create();
ps.AddScript(command);
var executionResult = await ps.InvokeAsync();
```

The error which I'm getting is:

```
System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Exception calling "FindAll" with "0" argument(s): "An operations error occurred.
```

Can anyone suggest how to execute it correctly?

Comment: Why don't you just use the class directly in C# instead using Powershell in C# to run this?

Comment: What @bluuf said. The underlying/real type name is [`DirectorySearcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @bluuf  What I'm doing is: I'm connecting to the remove machine using powershell, create DirectorySearcher there and execute it there. I have 2 goals: 1. find domain user by name 2. understand if a domain of a remote machine is Azure AD or not by searching for (&(OU=AADDC Users)). Same can be done using Get-ADDomain, but it requires PS module. Can the same be achieved from local machine using underlying types?

Comment: If you do Remote PowerShell from the PowerShell command line, does it work?